# SharpShell server .dll NOT signed

Tags: c#, shell, sharpshell

I need to develop a Shell Context Menu extension that references some other custom assemblies... I don't want to assign a Strong Name Key to those custom assemblies!

The [guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus?msg=5215253#xx5215253xx)  I followed to do this uses the SharpShell project and illustrates how to sign (but does not expalins why) the assembly... and this is my problem: if I sign my final .dll then I have many errors during my project's building phase, because some assemblies my project references are not strongly named ("Referenced assembly does not have a strong name").

In general, googling about the C# Shell Extension implementation, all best tutorials I found sign the final assembly... is it mandatory?

Without signing the assembly ServerManager.exe returns this error: "`The file 'XYZ.dll' is not a SharpShell Server`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I've solved my troubles... the `SharpShell.dll` file obtained through NuGet was a different version of the `ServerManager.exe` ones.
Uninstalling the SharpShell NuGet package and directly referencing the SharpShell.dll you find inside the ServerManager folder was my solution!

Moreover, I was looking between the article comments... please read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus?msg=4908204#xx4908204xx) question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use old DLL.
Please use this code directly, without using ServerManager.exe.

```
private static ServerEntry serverEntry = null;
        public static ServerEntry SelectedServerEntry
        {
            get
            {
                if (serverEntry == null)
                    serverEntry = ServerManagerApi.LoadServer("xxx.dll");
                return serverEntry;
            }
        }

public static ServerEntry LoadServer(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                //  Create a server entry for the server.
                var serverEntry = new ServerEntry();

                //  Set the data.
                serverEntry.ServerName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
                serverEntry.ServerPath = path;

                //  Create an assembly catalog for the assembly and a container from it.
                var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Path.GetFullPath(path));
                var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

                //  Get the exported server.
                var server = container.GetExport<ISharpShellServer>().Value;

                serverEntry.ServerType = server.ServerType;
                serverEntry.ClassId = server.GetType().GUID;
                serverEntry.Server = server;

                return serverEntry;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //  It's almost certainly not a COM server.
                MessageBox.Show("The file '" + Path.GetFileName(path) + "' is not a SharpShell Server.", "Warning");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Install code:

```
ServerRegistrationManager.InstallServer(SelectedServerEntry.Server, RegistrationType.OS64Bit, true);
```

Register code:

```
ServerRegistrationManager.RegisterServer(SelectedServerEntry.Server, RegistrationType.OS64Bit);
```